# Trying to return a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this method written up, but not sure why I'm getting errors. I'm still pretty new to programming, so does anyone see anything blatenly wrong with this?

```
public String[] gen() {
    String big = "A";
    String small = "a";
    return String[] {big, small};   
}
```

Note: Getting a redline under `return String[]`

Comment: `return new String[] {big, small};`

Comment: if you print the error you get, it will help us. anyway @Vincenzo response is the correct one.

Comment: 6 answers in like 20 seconds. What have I done.

Comment: but you still haven't accepted any of those answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
public String[] gen() {

            String big = "A";
            String small = "a";
            return new String[] {big, small};

    }

String[]{String, String} //is not a valid array constructor,
```

instead you should use

```
new String[]{String, String} constructor.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are omitting the `new` keyword.

```
return new String[] {big, small};
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the keyword `new`

```
return new String[] {big, small};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] gen() {

        String big = "A";
        String small = "a";
        return new String[] {big, small};
    }
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return new String[] {big, small};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to create string array using `new` keyword

```
public String[] gen() {

            String big = "A";
            String small = "a";
            return new String[] {big, small};

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `new` with array, use :

```
return new String[] {big, small};
```

```
public String[] gen() {    
        String big = "A";
        String small = "a";
        return new String[] {big, small};    
}
```